# data-ng-click does not work when element html is set from custom directive

Tags: angularjs

I have a custom directive to show contents when depending on if it is marked special:-

```
    myApp.directive('actionSpace', function() {
    //define the directive object
    var directive = {};

    //restrict = E, signifies that directive is Element directive
    directive.restrict = 'E';

    directive.link = function(scope, elem, attr) {
        console.log(scope.typeEv);
        if(attr.special == "1") {
            elem.html("");
        } else {
            elem.replaceWith('<div class="event-list-control"><button class="event-action-btn" data-ng-click="whoWas()"> '+
                        '<i class="fas fa-edit"></i>' +
                        '</button><button class="event-action-btn" data-ng-click="tellMe()">' +
                        '<i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button></div>');
        }
    }
    return directive;
    });
```

I can see in console directive's parent scope is available (its printing one of the variables), but data-ng-click does not work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to compile the inserted html before inserting it into the element, please refer the below example. I use the `$compile` method to make the `data-ng-click` work!

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MyController', function MyController($scope) {

});

app.directive('actionSpace', function($compile) {
    //define the directive object
    var directive = {};

    //restrict = E, signifies that directive is Element directive
    directive.restrict = 'E';

    directive.link = function(scope, elem, attr) {
        var html = ''
        scope.tellMe = function(){console.log("telling");}
        scope.whoWas = function(){console.log("this is");}
        if(attr.special == "1") {
            html = '';
        } else {
            html = '<div class="event-list-control"><button class="event-action-btn" data-ng-click="whoWas()">'+ '<i class="fas fa-edit"></i>' +
                        'Who Was</button><button class="event-action-btn" data-ng-click="tellMe()">' +
                        '<i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>Tell Me</button></div>';
        }
        var el = $compile(html)(scope);
    
        elem.append(el);
    }
    return directive;
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller='MyController' ng-app="myApp">
    <action-space></action-space>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of composing the template in the postLink function, do it in a template function:

```
myApp.directive('actionSpace', function() {
    //define the directive object
    var directive = {};

    //restrict = E, signifies that directive is Element directive
    directive.restrict = 'E';

    directive.template = function(tElem, tAttrs) {
        if (tAttrs.special == "1") {
            return "";
        } else {
            return `
              <div class="event-list-control">
                <button class="event-action-btn" data-ng-click="whoWas()">
                  <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>
                </button>
                <button class="event-action-btn" data-ng-click="tellMe()">
                  <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
                </button>
               </div>
            `; 
        };
    }
    return directive;
});
```

For more information, see [AngularJS Comprehensive Directive API Reference - template](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-template-)